# curl.lib missing (Visual Studio 2019, C++)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a project that require `curl.lib` but i tried every single tutorial that i have found online but noone helped me.

The first method that i have tried is just downloading `curl`, going to winbuild and to run some stuff with `nmake` but i'm getting some errors and after downloading `nmake` and `cl` i'm still getting an error (`return: 0xC0000135`) and i don't know how to fix this.

I have also tried some other methods like using vcpkg but i can't run vcpkg install curl because something goes wrong and i get this error: `Building package zlib:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED`

other tutorials are just not working and i spent 6 hours trying to solve this issue.

Any idea?

Comment: You probably should file a bug report on the vcpkg bug. With that said I can understand if you need this now that you have to try other solutions..

Comment: `0xC0000135` means dll not found. if the curl build produced a dll you need  to copy the dll into the same folder as your executable.

Comment: the curl build produced just some empty folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue using vcpkg, i discovered that this issue [enter-vsdevshell error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010139/enter-vsdevshell-in-visual-studio-2019-powershell-giving-error-filenotfoundexcep/65013062#65013062) was the problem and if someone had my same problem that's the fix.