# Enter-VsDevShell in Visual Studio 2019 Powershell giving error FileNotFoundException

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

Every time i open Visual Studio Powershell it just give me an error:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have my same problem update visual studio and if there's no update, just uninstall and reinstall it.